# How to display only a specific number of data to be displayed from the database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way that I can display around a specific number of items in an array instead of displaying all the products in the database?

**The main snippet that displays the products**

```
        //Fetch the data from the database
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT productID, productName, productPrice, productPic, productDescription FROM product_tbl ORDER BY productID DESC');
        $stmt->execute();

        //If the number of products is more than 0 
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            //Fetch the products from the database table to a row
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {   
                //Extract data to a row
                extract($row);
?>
    <!--Displays the products in a row of arrays-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <!--Product Image--> 
            <!--Product Name--> 
            <!--Product Price and Details-->
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use Limit and offset in your query

Comment: Use limit in your select query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use `limit and offset` for that

```
select * from tablename order by id desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

for more info you can visit
[click here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

describes that `LIMIT` is only allowed to appear after the `ORDER BY`.